# Delphi PageControl with TabSheet invisibleTabVisible := False;

Tags: delphi

I have a Form with a PageControl with 7 Tab.
I want to see only some Tabs. On one side the Tab 0,1,2,3,4, and 5, and on the other side only the tab 6 and 7. I render then, in turn, invisible.
I have a DBNavigator which change the DataSource in the procedure DBNavigatorClik to control the grid etc on the used tab.

As an exemple with 2 Tab

```
procedure TF_DatenErfassung.PageControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  with (Sender as TPageControl) do
   case PageControl1.Tabindex of
  0:begin 
    DBNavigator1.DataSource:=F_ModuleTables.DS_MieteBezahlung;
   end;                                                                                                                 
  1:begin 
    DBNavigator1.DataSource:=F_ModuleTables.DS_T_JaresAbrechnung_Mieter;      
   end;
 end;{case}
end;
```

In the FormActivate procedure I have
this code:

```
if ModuleTables.T_TABLE.FieldByName('NrDossier').AsString[1]<>'X' then

{A}  begin
      PageControl1.Pages[0].TabVisible:=false;
      PageControl1.Pages[1].TabVisible:=true; {I want to work only on this Tab}
     end
    else
{B}  begin
      PageControl1.Pages[0].TabVisible:=true; {I want to work only on this Tab}
      PageControl1.Pages[1].TabVisible:=false;
    end;
```

When I am on the {A} on my form PageControl the Tab 1 is obviously the first one (in that case the only one) the Tab 0 is not visible and only the Tab 1 is visibled. But it seems that for the pageControl this is the Tab 0 and not 1 It just change the Tab Index; Is there a way to go around; I try to put in a

```
 PageControl1.ActivePageIndex:=1;
```

but it doesn't care. It seems to me that the Tab index is in reallity create when the page is created which doesn't make a problem but in my case it's make a problem.
Is there a way to go around it without to recreate the all "wheel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *Tabs* and *Pages*. *Tabs* are the tabs of the visible  pages. So if only one tab is visible that tab/page has always *TabIndex = 0*.

The case statement in *PageControl1Change* should act on `PageControl1.ActivePageIndex` instead of `PageControl1.TabIndex`.